# Inputting two or more values to the database simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new with PHP, am I doing this right? The function of the code below will put the 2 values inside the database simultaneously. Once I input the values in the 2 text boxes, only the value in the first textbox is stored into the database. How can I store these two values into database with one form?

**add.php**

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);


    mysql_close($con);
    ?> 

    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="form1">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    Firstname1: <input type="text" name="firstname" />

    Age: <input type="text" name="age" />



    <input type="submit" name="form1" />
    </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

**insert.php**

```
        <html>
     <head>
      <title>Record Added</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=select.php">
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO biodata (FirstName)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[firstname]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?> 

    <a href="select.php"> see</a>

     </body>
    </html>
```

**select.php**

```
    <?php
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUser = 'root';
    $dbPass = '';
    $dbName = 'my_database';

    $dbConn = mysql_connect ($dbHost,$dbUser, $dbPass) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());

    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Display</title>
    </head>
    <table align="center" border=1>
    <tr>
    <th> First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name </th>
    <th> Age </th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM biodata";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $row['FirstName'];?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php }?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're only selecting from the database you're not adding to the database.

Comment: Please note that `mysql_` functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore (at least for production code).

Comment: Yes, the code will list the values, to add them use `INSERT INTO` command instead of `SELECT`.

Comment: I guess it's a typo and that both fields have the same name `FirstName`. Use `FirstName[]` instead and in your PHP `$_POST['FirstName']` will be an indexed array containing your two values.

Comment: No its not a typo. Its just the way I think it is. What I want to happen is to put 2 "FirstName" in to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [UPDATE] TRY THIS:

Send your values from the form as arrays as access the second input. If not, your record would get overwritten. You can't really have two form fields with the same name except they form an array. This should be your best option. Here we are storing both values in same table in two columns.

#### Your Form

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="verify">
<font color="#FFFF00">Name:</font> <input type="text" name="FistName[0]" />
<font color="#FFFF00">Name:</font> <input type="text" name="FirstName[1]"/>

<input type="submit" value="add" name="verify"/>
```

#### Use this to add textbox 2 into database

```
<?php
$names = $_POST["FirstName"];
$FirstName_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($names[0]);
$FirstName_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($names[1]);

$query = "INSERT INTO biodata (FirstName_1, FirstName_2)
VALUES ('" . $FirstName_1 . "', '" . $FirstName_2 . "') ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
```

#### Use this to display from database

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM biodata";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row["FirstName_1"];?></td>
</tr>
```

#### To add two or more values to a database, follow this example in w3schools using mysqli (Note mysql is deprecated).

```
<?php
//Filename: insert.php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Your form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Run a simple course here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: You said you need to input the second input value, right? FirstName is posted as an array with length of 2. Post receives it and puts the value on the second array in DB. Can I know what error you got and how you are collecting the values for the two input fields? I'm guessing users is entering value in input text field 1, so how are you coming up with the value for input text field 2? I'm sure you won't be asking your users to input their firstnames twice.

Comment: ***Know how can I store these two values into database with 1 form.*** Does this mean you want to store values for firstname textfield 1 and firstname textfield 2 in the same database or in two different databases? What are the column names in the database? Check my updated answer for storing the two values in same table of a database

Comment: I want to store values for firstname textfield 1 and firstname textfield 2 in the same database.  When I input the values it doesn't add on the database. My code above is just a sample. Thats not the real flow of my system I was trying to make. I just want to know how can I add 2 or more values to the database simultaneously.

Comment: You said this: ***"No its not a typo. Its just the way I think it is. What I want to happen is to put 2 "FirstName" in to the database."*** You cannot have two columns in one database table bearing the name FirstName. I'd like to know your table name and column names. Have you tried the edit I made above, a quicker response would help you better. If it's just the regular add 2 or more values to database, Then use the mysql insert statement as you should, Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: There is my code of all the pages i made. I've tried to run your code but I really can't get it. I'am really new on php sir. Can you pls give me an example by modifying my code? All I just want to know is to store 2 or more values to the database.

Comment: @Miggy, we would need to know your table structure into your question to help you further. Please edit this into the end of your question. Also, try not to use phrases here such as "Doesn't work" and "I really can't get it" etc - tell us what you _tried_ to make it work, and where you think it is failing. We're here to help, not to write your code for you `:)`

Comment: Thanks halfer, just about to mention that. We really can breed newbies in StackOverflow, we just help with developers questions. I can't go further until I get matching response from you. First, answer all the questions and requests I have made above. Tell me if you've practised the w3schools lessons I posted for you. Give me the error messages you get in return. Next try voting up helps that you get. Don't work sounds like a response to paid contractors. I expect, tried it and got this error. Ball is in your court.